# Memcache with both rails and php

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, serialization, memcached, marshalling

I am trying to share my memcache server with my rails and php server.

Rails:

```
my_var = {'one'=>1,'two'=>2}
Rails.cache.write 'hello', PHP.serialize(my_var), :raw => true
Rails.cache.read 'hello'
```

output:

```
"a:2:{s:3:\"one\";i:1;s:3:\"two\";i:2;}"
```

PHP:

```
$var = self::$memcache->get('hello');
die(var_dump($var));
```

output:

```
"a:2:{s:3:\"one\";i:1;s:3:\"two\";i:2;}"
```

PHP.serialize is a function from gem php_serialize. 
I was hoping that my PHP server can pickup hello and produces an array. Could anyone please help me which part that I do wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memcached gives back the serialized (marshaled) string. To use the actual array, you need to unserialize it in PHP first, just like you have to serialize the array in Ruby.

Try

```
$var = unserialize(self::$memcache->get('hello'));
die(var_dump($var));
```

Comment: Thank you. It works like you said. the thing is that my php is a legacy code, and I am trying not to change anything there. I was hoping I can work something out from the Rails side. Another issue is that, in PHP `code`$hello = array('one'=>1,'two'=>2);
self::$memcache->set('hello',$hello,false, false);
$var = self::$memcache->get('hello');die(var_dump($var));`code` will output `code`array(2) { ["one"]=> int(1) ["two"]=> int(2) }`code` but from the rails side: `code`Rails.cache.read('hello')`code` outputs `code`"a:2:{s:4:\"satu\";i:1;s:3:\"dua\";i:2;}"`code`. So why PHP do unserialize here?

Comment: This has probably something to do with your PHP class. Are you using a PHP class or the memcached extension? If you are using the class, try to understand what it does when you call the set method.

Answer (score 0):

[Serialisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) for PHP and here ruby means that you transform the object to a textual representation, a flat string. In PHP this would be done with the function [serialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). To actually have a new instance of the passed object you would thus need to recreate it from this textual representation for which you need another function in PHP [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

So here in your case like @chiborg said, using unserialize would get your array

```
var_dump(unserialize("a:2:{s:3:\"one\";i:1;s:3:\"two\";i:2;}"));

array(2) {
  ["one"]=>
  int(1)
  ["two"]=>
  int(2)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I wish I had set the notification to my email so I can accept your answer right away.